# Stop flight training and start again in a different country

Tags: flight-training, ppl

Is it possible to put PPL flight training (started in the US) on hold and pick it up again in a different (European) country? Would one have to start all over again or would the US training be recognized as valid?

I understand it's a pandora box question with many details under the hood but I was wondering if anyone has ever experienced something similar and can share their thoughts.